# Problem in command execution in Ruby

Tags: ruby, command-prompt

I am executing commands in Ruby using `system command`, but I am facing the following problem:

I **load an environment** using the command `Environment.bat`, and I want to **execute** the **second command** which **makes use of the environment** that I have set up successfully in the previous command. However, it seems as if loading the environment earlier does not have any effect at all.

How to solve this problem so that the environment that I load in the ruby shell is used in the commands that I execute afterwards.

Comment: what does 'environment' look like? Is that a set of system variables or something? It might really help if you show some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to "chain" your two commands so that they get executed in the same [system subshell](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001441).  That is, if you're executing two commands in separate ruby "system" calls then they are modifying the environments of separate child programs which are not directly related.

```
system("env.bat") # Executes in child process 1.
system("program.exe") # Executes in child process 2.
```

In the above example, "program.exe" wouldn't know if "env.bat" had changed the environment by adding a new environment variable (for example) since they run in separate, unrelated processes.

```
system("env.bat && program.exe") # Both in the same child process.
```

But in this example the two commands are run in the same subshell process, one after the other, as long as "env.bat" doesn't exit with an error code.  In this case "program.exe" would have access to any new environment variables set by "env.bat".